# language of bitstrings with no more than 3 consecutive zeros generating function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, formal-languages, automata

I am trying to find the generating function of a sequence in the language of bitstrings, $X$, where each bitstring contains no more than 3 consecutive zeros.

I have come up with the recurrence relation for a sequence $h_n$ of length $n$ as follows: (I am not 100% sure that it is correct, either)

> $h_n=h_{n-1}+h_{n-2}+h_{n-3} + h_{n-4}$

How do I derive a generating function using this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recursion like this leads to a function equation: define $H(x) = \sum_n h_nx^n$.
Then $H(x) = h_0 + h_1x h_2x^2 + h_3x^3 + \sum_{n \ge 4} h_nx^n$.

The last part can be replaced using the recursion:

$$\sum_{n \ge 4} (h_{n-1} + h_{n-2} + h_{n-3} + h_{n-4})x^n = x\sum_{n \ge 4} h_{n-1} x^{n-1} + x^2 \sum_{n \ge 4} h_{n-2}x^{n-2} + x^3 \sum_{n \ge 4} h_{n-3}x^{n-3} +\\ x^4 \sum_{n \ge 4} h_{n-4}x^{n-4}$$

Now note that $\sum_{n \ge 4} h_{n-4}x^{n-4} = \sum_n h_n x^n = H(x)$ again, while $\sum_{n \ge 4} h_{n-3}x^{n-3} = H(x) - h_0$ etc.

Working it all out gives an equation into $H(x)$ that you can hopefully solve...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would you be able to link me any sources which make this a bit easier to follow? (I have very few notes on generating functions, and results from google are at a much higher level than I am used to) I have accepted your answer!

Comment: Generatingfunctionology. By Wilf is available online IIRC

Comment: Why is the second term in the generating function $h_1xh_2x^2$?

Comment: I also don't understand how $\sum_{n \ge 4} h_{n-4}x^{n-4} = \sum_n h_n x^n = H(x)$, could you please explain?

Comment: Just reindexing. Write out the first few terms.

Comment: Taking out $x$ decreases the index of the $x^n$ term to $x^{n-1}$ using the same index. And $H(X)$ is defined as having corresponding indexes: $h_k$ with $x^k$ everywhere. So hence the extra index shuffling and pulling out the variable as well. Write out the first few terms and all should be clearer.